# Add reference to other C# projects in visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing

I have a C# console application project in visual studio 2015. I have a project with name **MyPrograms** in this solution. There are some classes and a main test method in this project. I have another (C# **Unit Test**) project in the same solution with name **MyUnitTests**.
I have set the target framework of **MyPrograms** to **.Net Framework 4 Client Profile** and **.Net Framework 4.5** of MyUnitTests project. I have also added the reference of MyPrograms project in my MyUnitTests project.

Now I want to access class files of MyPrograms project in my MyUnitTests project. I am accessing class files of MyPrograms project with the **using** statements in the classes of MyUnitTests project. But I am unable to access those classes.

I have also tried it by changing various target frameworks of both the projects.
I have tried different things as well as explained in the following links.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez524kew.aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ez524kew(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You don't access _files_ in other projects, you add a _reference_ to the project and use the _types (classes) from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same problem was solved in my case by following these things.
If your MyPrograms project is a console application, it will generate exe file but not dll file.
In your MyUnitTests project, add reference of both .exe file and .vshost from path
YourProject/bin/Debug/... 
Also try to change Platform to x64 from configuration manager and build your both projects.
Also to Any CPU if previously was x64 and again build both the solutions.